# Remove official repository from QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, repository

I would like to remove the official repository from several QGIS installations.

Removing the Repository from the Settings works so far with:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
settings=QSettings()

test=settings.allKeys()
for i in test:
    if u'Qgis/plugin-repos/' in i:
        if u'/url' in i:
            if settings.value(i)==u'https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml':
                repo_key = i.rsplit('/', 1)[0]
                settings.setValue(i,'')
                settings.remove(repo_key);
```

But as soon as QGIS is started the next time the repository is added to the settings again.

How can I remove it permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to remove the official repository by removing it during startup and replacing the official repository with my repository by editing the installer_data.py of the QGIS installation.

I just replaced the line where the official repository is defined:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/ec2ddb4295badd6953237e5e9182b7903f429e5a/python/pyplugin_installer/installer_data.py#L97

```
old:
officialRepo = (QCoreApplication.translate("QgsPluginInstaller", "QGIS Official Plugin Repository"), "https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml")

new:
officialRepo = ("my Repository name", "my repository url")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but the official repository can't be deleted. 
Every time you open QGIS it's reset (file [installer_data.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/ec2ddb4295badd6953237e5e9182b7903f429e5a/python/pyplugin_installer/installer_data.py), on my pc "*C: \ OSGeo4W64 \ apps \ qgis-ltr \ python \ pyplugin_installer \ installer_data.py* ").

To avoid this you can create a [startup.py](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#run-python-code-when-qgis-starts) file, but I do not know if it can work.

Another solution is to make a [minimal plugin](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qgis-minimal-plugin), that simply execute that code, that way you could avoid it and you will only have to copy that plugin in those machines

Comment: I had already added the code in the startup.py but even if the setting is deleted during startup the repository exists in the plugin manager. If a plugin removes the settings after startup the  result is the same